# How to connect a Fritz!Box as a SIP client to Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, fax

My planned setup is as follows:

Analog Fax machine -> Fritz!Box -> Asterisk -> Telephone network

My problem is, how do I convince the Fritz!Box to connect as a SIP client to my Asterisk instance?

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction:

http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/fritz_box.html

(this was the first hit off google for "Fritz!Box asterisk")

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with FritzBox and Asterisk servers it's most probably better, to let the FritzBox connect directly to the VOIP provider to send out faxes. 
I tried it to connect the FritzBox to the Asterisk server and then send out faxes, but the connection was quite unstable. I had more and better luck with letting the Fritzbox connect directly to the voip provider.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need one of these: http://www.voipsupply.com/voip-adapters/single-fxs

I'm not familiar with fritz!box, but one of those adapters will probably take care of getting your fax machine going with your asterisk box.